# Dummy variable for first of the month

Tags: python

The crux of this is that its stock data, so the first day of the month might not always be the 1st. I have found a way of isolating these, but i don't know how to then edit the dataframe to put a "1" next to each of these.

Hopefully this makes sense.

```
import pandas_datareader as web
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

df = web.DataReader('AAPL', 'google')

df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['Date']))
df.sort_index(inplace=True)

print(df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='MS')).nth(0))
```

The code i'm using. Currently it prints the first of the month correctly, but i'm not sure how to make a new column (D_FoM) with a 1 at every one of these dates.

I'm sure its something easy but i cant work it out, R is much easier for this sort of thing i feel.